# SyntaxError: [stdin]:24:11: unexpected . React-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I'm trying to make form with `react-rails` gem. But I receive an error:

> SyntaxError: [stdin]:24:11: unexpected .

By trial I've found, that problem is in first `React.DOM.div` line (it's marked in code), but I don't understand, why it's happened, I've checked everything one hundred times :)

**components/country_form.coffee**:

```
@CountryForm = React.createClass
    getInitialState: ->
        name: ''

    valid: ->
        @state.name

    handleChange: (e) ->
        name = e.target.name
        @setState "#{name}": e.target.value

    handleSubmit: (e) ->
        e.preventDefault()
        $.post '', { country: @state }, (data) =>
            @props.handleNewCountry data
            @setState @getInitialState()
        , 'JSON'

    render: ->
        React.DOM.form
            onSubmit: @handleSubmit
            React.DOM.div # Problem is here
                className: 'form-group'
                    React.DOM.label
                        'Name'
                    React.DOM.input
                        type: 'text'
                        className: 'form-control'
                        name: 'name'
                        value: @state.name
                        onChange: @handleChange
            React.DOM.div
                className: 'form-group'
                    React.DOM.button
                        type: 'submit'
                        className: 'btn btn-primary'
                        disabled: !@valid()
                        'Save'
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem. RubyMine (and I think IntelliJ IDEA too) indent CoffeeScript files with spaces. Just change indentations to tabs, and error will disappear.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA settings (CoffeeScript indentions)]

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be indented once more.

Right now it's even with the `prop` of `onSubmit`:

```
    React.DOM.form
        onSubmit: @handleSubmit
        React.DOM.div # Problem is here
            className: 'form-group'
```

but maybe it should be incremented once more:

```
    React.DOM.form
        onSubmit: @handleSubmit
        # -> 
            React.DOM.div # Problem is here
                className: 'form-group'
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. The problem was with indentation, I've added the answer.